# Code will not stop when the for loop is broken

Tags: c#, game-physics

I have tried searching for an answer but i have not found anything. I'm making this 2d game in c# where i want the player to be pulled down by the force which increases by gravity each time the function in called (inside a while loop). For some reason the code will not stop when the for loop is broken.

```
private void PhysicsLoop()
{
    NowX = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(Player.x / 32)));
    NowY = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(Player.y / 32)));

    if (Block[NowX,NowY + 2].Collides == false)
    {
        Falling = true;
    }

    if (Falling == true)
    {
        force += Gravity;
        for (int i = 0; i <= force; i++)
        {
            if (Block[NowX, NowY + 2].Collides == true)
            {
                Falling = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Player.y += 1;
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `force += Gravity;` should this be inside your for loop..? I would suggest first setting breakpoints and use the debugger..

Comment: What do you mean by *"the code will not stop"*? You mentioned this method is being called inside a `while` loop. It sounds like that is where the problem is, because the code you have shown above looks fine (except the unnecessary, empty `else` block).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what platform you're trying to program on, whether it be Console, Winforms, XNA, or whatever else it may be, however, I will try and help you with this.

I noticed you have two values that you kind of set for comparison, these being `NowX` and `NowY`. I also notice that you are converting to a decimal, thn back to an Int32.

So my first suggestion that you check is the the objects you are colliding with aren't somehow set to a decimal, float, or double value. Because if they are, then your Collision most likely will never be true, thus getting the infinite loop.

My second thought is that I notice in your if statement that you have the code `Player.y += 1` but nowhere do you have something that makes the y value decrease, so maybe the code loop is breaking, just that since the y value is always raised, the loop is always raising it since the first time the Blocks y value might have been 1, and player.y was 2, then the second time around Blocks was still 1 and player.y was 7 or something similar to that.

You might Edit your question and add some more code to the question, like maybe what starts or calls `PhysicsLoop`, or the `Collides` method code.

If ever I needed jumping physics in some sort of game, I would follow the same kind of code that was used for good ol' Mario and have an enum with constants to manage the jump physics

```
enum JumpValues
{
    float StartingVelocity = 1.0F;
    float StartingToSlow = 0.5F;
    float PeakOfJump = 0.0F;
    float StartingToFall = -0.5F;
    float MaxFallSpeed = -1.0F;
}
```

then use a separate thread to manage the players y value and run through the motions of the enum JumpValues.

I don't know if this helps you or even kind of lets you see where to start looking for errors, but I hope it helps. Good Luck Coding :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. First of all I'm using Windows forms app. To clarify some things, Gravity is a constant, collides is a bool and im not trying to make the Y decrease but get the loop to stop. What the loop is doing is that the force will increase by Gravity (2) each time. The for loop runs force amount of times where it will add 1 to the y position. So in the first game loop, Player y will increase by two and in the second it will increase by 4 and so on.

Comment: The reason it is in a loop is so that i can check if it has reached the floor level but for some reason it doesn't stop until the full force has been added. The player will then fall into the ground below which is handled in the graphics method. If you need any more info just ask but i doubt you would really need more code.

Comment: Well I just ran a few tests of my own (in a slightly separate environment of course) and I was able to get it to break in every scenario I tested. You said that Collides was a bool, so I'm willing to bet that some mathematical intricacy in how it collides with the ground is off by something, so that `Block[NowX, NowY + 2].Collides`, never equals true. Annoying as it is, I would either have the program output the Players X and Y values to a log, or Message Boxes, to see exactly what values the Player has been going by. Another way is literally just by running through the program line by line.